# how to override mvc component in joomla 3?

Tags: joomla-3.x

How to override the any component controller model files using plugin in joomla is there any documentation for that?. I found documentation very old in joomla articles.

i have been trying to create a plugin like this

```
<?php

class PlgSystemComcontentoverride extends JPlugin {
      public function __construct(&$subject, $config = array()) {
         parent::__construct($subject, $config);
     }

     public function onAfterRoute() {
         $app = JFactory::getApplication();
         if('com_content' == JRequest::getCMD('option') && !$app->isAdmin()) {
             require_once('/var/www/html/joomla3913/templates/protostar/code/com_content/my_content_controller.php');
         }
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant override the controller or models of a component, only the view using https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

But, Joomla ships with a variety of core events, organised into groups where you can manipulate the data who is handle in those models and controls. https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events

For example, if you want to have access to the data who was saved in the database after save a article, you can do a plugin like this one:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

class PlgContentWebp extends CMSPlugin
{
    /**
     * Example after save content method
     *
     * @param   string   $context  The context of the content passed to the plugin
     * @param   object   $article  A TableContent object
     * @param   boolean  $isNew    If the content is just about to be created
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     */
    public function onContentAfterSave($context, $article, $isNew): void
    {
       // Check if is inside the administrator area
        $app = Factory::getApplication();
        if (!$app->isClient('administrator')) {
            return;
        }

        // Check if is a article edition view
        if ($context != 'com_content.article') {
            return;
        }

        // Here you can do anything with the $article data, 
        // for example get the images who was saved
        
        $images = json_decode($article->images);
    }
}
```